# Kendo pop up window is very small after updating with latest release

Tags: popup, window, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo open source Web UI.

I have pop up window in the application. It was working fine. 
I updated to the latest released source from kendo site and The pop up window became very small, it's not clearly visible and the main page goes in the background.

How can I fix that ?

Should I move back to JQuery or should I continue with kendo hoping the fix for these issues will come soon?

Comment: if (!dataDtls.data("kendoWindow")) {
  dataDtls.kendoWindow({
  draggable : true,
  modal : true,
  resizable : true,
  visible : false,
  title : "View Details",
  width: "500px"
  });
 }
      
****************************************************      
dataDtls.data("kendoWindow").center();
dataDtls.data("kendoWindow").open();

Comment: I debugged it  the problem is   -webkit-transform: scale(0.01);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with changes between jQuery 1.7 and 1.8. Please upgrade the jQuery you're using to 1.8 and the issue will go away (or use the latest Kendo UI internal builds).

Comment: Updated jquery to jquery-1.8.3.min.js  , Now it is working 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my best bug during my last day

you have to update to latest jQuery version

but remember jQuery 1.8 has a bug with outerHeight function that return object not integer if calling outerHeight() without param

so u can update to 1.8 and edit the kendo.web.js file replace any call outerHeight()

to outerHeight(true)